# check if a file exist in windows server from linux server, copy if file exist

Tags: linux, windows, script, shell-script

Is there a way to check if a file exist in windows server from a linux server, and copy to linux server if file exist without mounting the windows fs to linux. Perhaps a public key? but not sure how to start. I want to write a script to check if a file exist in windows server and copy it to linux server if it does.

Comment: (1) Almost any sane method of copying a file simply throws an error if the source does not exist, so checking for existence in advance is hardly ever needed. (2) What protocols does the server support that may allow you to transfer files? Different protocols give different answers to "how can I copy a file?". (3) What are your reasons behind this "without mounting" requirement? Maybe you want solutions that don't require root access. What about [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)?

Answer (score -1):

if your windows server has apache or any http/ftp/sftp server then you can easily use curl   for example :

```
funker()
{ 
lic=$(curl http://192.168.0.138/lic.txt) #reads the file on the remote server

if [ $lic == encoder ] #checks if file has the desired content
then 
echo "file detected" #true statement
#cat a status file readable by other scripts
cat > /path to file/enc_stat.txt << EOF 
true
EOF
else 
echo "file not detected"

cat > /path to file/enc_stat.txt << EOF
false
EOF
fi
}
```

this is for status if you explicitly need to know if the file exists
the above can also be achieved by

```
status=$(curl http://192.168.0.138/lic.txt | wc -l)
```

if you need to download/copy it then you can just

```
curl -O http://192.168.0.138/lic.txt
```

(this will download and save the file with the same name as the orignal file)

```
curl -o newname.txt http://192.168.0.138/lic.txt
```

(this will let you download a file while assigning a new name or a new path and name for the file)

i made a sh based systemd service to automate this
hope i could help

Comment: How will that work if the file if the file is not available via the servers web service? Perhaps they want to find out if `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` exists.

Comment: this will tell them if the file is available or not it was already mentioned in the orignal answer   status=$(curl http://192.168.0.138/lic.txt | wc -l)